# How can I access a specific control in a user-created tab in the ribbon?

Tags: vba, ms-word, ribbonx

I'm having trouble accessing a specific button in the MS Word ribbon using VBA. So far, I've got very little as far as code, because no matter where I search and what string I use on Google, the Internet has come up with bupkes. I know that I need to access the ribbon itself using `CommandBars("Ribbon")`, but when I try to iterate through all the controls in `CommandBars("Ribbon")`, it has a grand total of one control. What the...? Only one control in the entire ribbon? You're off your rocker, VBA.

I've run this code to get a list of controls:

```
Dim Counter As Integer
For Counter = 1 To CommandBars("Ribbon").Controls.Count
    Debug.Print CommandBars("Ribbon").Controls(Counter).TooltipText
Next Counter
```

And, strangely enough, I get only that one control back, and the tooltip text is "Tas&k Pane." (I get this when running the macro from both Word itself and the VBA window.)

Does anyone know how I can access a specific user-defined tab in the ribbon so I can get access to read properties on a specific control?

Answer (score 0):

The `CommandBars` property returns a `CommandBars` object that represents the Microsoft Word command bars. Used with the `Application` object, this property returns the set of built-in and custom command bars available to the application. But it doesn't contain ribbon controls. If you need to perform any action against the command bars controls you may use [CommandBars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.commandbars) methods. For example, you can check whether a particular control is visible or not passing the `idMso` name of the built-in control:

```
 Application.CommandBars.GetVisibleMso("Bold")
```

The Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12))
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12))
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12))

Comment: This does not address the question asked: "Does anyone know how I can access a specific **user-defined tab** in the ribbon so I can get access to read properties on a specific control?"

Comment: Some properties can be read by using `CommandBars` methods. The `CommandBars` object doesn't contain ribbon controls. That's what it states. Do you still think that it didn't answer the question?

Comment: My end goal for this time is to read the icon used for a ribbon control in a user-defined ribbon tab. I want to take that icon and apply it to the FaceId of a context-menu/right-click-menu option. Is that possible in MS Word? I've been combing the Internet for any clue on how to do this, but I haven't found anything that helps. I'll check the links that @EugeneAstafiev posted above, but in the meantime....

Comment: You must extract the icon or image and use it for your custom UI. The Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) doesn't provide anything for doing such actions at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

By design, it is not possible to address a user-defined Ribbon control through VBA. The reason for this design decision is that, in the days of toolbars/command bars (pre-Word 2007) too many "add-ins" were subverting these so that the Office applications were not working the way people expected them to - and Microsoft usually got the blame for "buggy software".

So Ribbon XML is "sand-boxed". There are some limited commands in the `CommandBars` object model that allow checking whether a *built-in* Ribbon control is visible, or enabled, and allows execution of that control. But this does not extend to custom Ribbon controls - those are "private" to the project that defines them.

*If* the "owner" of a Ribbon customization consciously enables "sharing" of any Ribbon controls (through the use of `idQ`) it's possible to access them  (using "callbacks") through another Ribbon XML solution, running in parallel. But that's the only exception.